# Deja Vu - What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

You know I think I've been here before,
And very soon I am shown the door.
Someone new brought me here,
To another place I will steer.

Little can be done to fix,
I shouldn't even be in the mix.
I must already be known,
Who am I? Not really alone.

Comment: Did you put the peanut butter in the fridge again!? It's becoming self conscious.

Comment: @MarkN I think it's coming after me. Save me!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer is

> a plagiarized question on PuzzlingSE

You know I think I've been here before,

> Every now and again new users join and add cliched riddles and puzzles without any attribution.

And very soon I am shown the door.

> Emrakul brings down his hammer on these questions and off they go into the garbage bin.

Someone new brought me here,

> As mentioned, such questions are often brought up by new users on PuzzlingSE.

To another place I will steer.

> Their clues can very easily lead us to the actual source with a simple Google search.

Little can be done to fix,

> We can downvote and flag repeatedly, and Emrakul can delete them but little can be done to fix this issue permanently.

I shouldn't even be in the mix.

> In an ideal scenario, we should never have to deal with such plagiarized questions.

I must already be known,

> Most of the plagiarized riddles and puzzles are already known to the expert puzzlers here.

Who am I? Not really alone.

> You are a plagiarized question, and there can be several of you hanging around on PuzzlingSE even after Emrakul and the community's vigilante efforts.

This answer is inspired by [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/what-is-the-criteria-for-question-deletion-on-puzzling-se).

Comment: I just recently read that meta post as well :-o!

Comment: I was thinking a little more innocent than this, but in a way this is what I was thinking.

Comment: @AggieKidd: Holy cow! I wasn't even serious when I posted this answer. :-P

Comment: @CodeNewbie Hehe. I had wanted to do this one for a while, but then I read the afore mentioned metapost and it came to me again.

Answer (score 5):

Could it be:

> A shopping cart (With short term memory loss)

You know I think I've been here before,

And very soon I am shown the door.

> A shopping cart is often pushed to the front entrance of the store, where it can be shown the door.

Someone new brought me here,

> A shopping cart is reused by many people. Here a new customer is pushing it into the store!

To another place I will steer.

> It will steer into the store, and possibly down many isles.

Little can be done to fix,

> A possible reference to how shopping carts always seem to have at least one broken wheel, and no matter how hard you try to compensate, that wheel will not cooperate.

I shouldn't even be in the mix.

> Broken shopping carts shouldn't be in the 'mix' of normal shopping carts (as they are damaged).

I must already be known,

Who am I? Not really alone

> You, are a broken shopping cart, and I will always be here for you.

Comment: +1 I like it, but no. There are a couple of clues that you haven't addressed that are key.

Comment: @AggieKidd Shopping carts can have keys... :-p

Comment: It's a great answer even if it's not the right one!